# Cómo verificar si una contraseña contiene símbolos (?!¡@¿.,´) en Java

Tags: java

tengo una duda, tengo el siguiente código para validar si una contraseña tiene más de 12 caracteres, mínimo una letra mayúscula y mínimo un número. Mi pregunta es, como podría hacer para validar si tiene mínimo un símbolo? Gracias de antemano.

```
public static boolean contraseñaSegura(String contraseña) {

    if (contraseña.length() > 12) {
        boolean mayuscula = false;
        boolean numero = false;
        boolean simbolo = false;
        int i;
        char l;

        for (i = 0; i < contraseña.length(); i++) {
            l = contraseña.charAt(i);

            if (Character.isDigit(l)) {
                numero = true;
            }
            if (Character.isUpperCase(l)) {
                mayuscula = true;
            }
        }

            if (numero == true && mayuscula == true) {
                return true;
            }else {
                return false;
            }
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que requieres es que tu método verifique:

- una contraseña tiene más de 12 caracteres.
- mínimo una letra mayúscula
- mínimo un número.
- contiene símbolos (?!¡@¿.,´)

Es casí correcto como lo estas realizando, en el caso de una letra o simbolos puedes usar simplemente:

```
  if (Character.isLetter(l)) {//contiene letras o símbolos (?!¡@¿.,´)
       letraOsimbolo = true;
  }
```

**Pero si lo que quieres es definir los "caracteres especiales" que deseas sean validados puedes definir un patrón conteniendo los caracteres que deseas y usar la clase `Matcher` para verificarlos**

```
    //Define caracteres especiales
    Pattern special = Pattern.compile ("[?!¡@¿.,´)]");
    Matcher hasSpecial = special.matcher(contrasena);
    if(hasSpecial.find()){
       //Contiene caracteres especiales.   
       especial = true;
   }
```

por lo tanto tu método cambiaría a (por cierto como buena práctica evita usar palabras acentuadas como nombres de clase o métodos) :

```
public static boolean contrasenaSegura(String contrasena) {

    if (contrasena.length() > 12) { //una contraseña tiene más de 12 caracteres.
        boolean mayuscula = false;
        boolean numero = false;
        boolean letraOsimbolo = false;
        boolean especial = false;

        //Define caracteres especiales
        Pattern special = Pattern.compile("[?!¡@¿.,´)]");
        Matcher hasSpecial = special.matcher(contrasena);

        int i;
        char l;

        for (i = 0; i < contrasena.length(); i++) {
            l = contrasena.charAt(i);

            if (Character.isDigit(l)) {//mínimo un número. 
                numero = true;
            }
            if (Character.isLetter(l)) {//contiene letras o símbolos (?!¡@¿.,´)
                letraOsimbolo = true;
            }
            if (Character.isUpperCase(l)) { // mínimo una letra mayúscula 
                mayuscula = true;
            }
            if (hasSpecial.find()) { //Valida "caracteres especiales".       
                especial = true;
            }
        }

        if (numero == true && mayuscula == true && letraOsimbolo == true && especial == true) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

Ejemplos:

```
System.out.println("contraseña Segura: => " + contrasenaSegura("Jorge"));
System.out.println("contraseña Segura: => " + contrasenaSegura("Stackoverflow12"));
System.out.println("contraseña Segura: => " + contrasenaSegura("IasiromaniaJorgesys12"));
System.out.println("contraseña Segura: => " + contrasenaSegura("Jorgesys@12345"));
System.out.println("contraseña Segura: => " + contrasenaSegura("?Jorgesys12345"));
System.out.println("contraseña Segura: => " + contrasenaSegura("Jorgesys1234.5"));
```

salida:

```
contraseña Segura: => false
contraseña Segura: => false
contraseña Segura: => false
contraseña Segura: => true
contraseña Segura: => true
contraseña Segura: => true
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!! :D